# Use React components UI in Node express application with EJS templates

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ejs, primereact

I have to upgrade an existing application with new features. It is an MPA web application, developed using the express framework under Node, and serving the HTML from EJS templates. I'm ok about using vanilla JS/jQuery but I'm curious if it would be possible to integrate a React based UI component library, like [PrimeReact](https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/), to use some of its components in the EJS files to make the development easier.

I know that I should install and configure Babel for transpiling the JSX but I couldn't find any examples about how to do it and how to use the React component in the EJS template.

Anyone with a similar case? Cheers!

Comment: You can leverage renderToString function of React, to render a react component inside ejs templates or even ejs.render(), for using renderToString, you;ll need a babel preset, otherwise its a no-go. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181682/using-express-and-es6-to-render-react-and-jsx-server-side) is an example.

Comment: Hi! I've checked the link you provided and also some articles but I have too many doubts and too little time. For now, I'll use jQuery and I'll update the question as soon as I have time to do some tests with the React components. Thanks!