# @babel/preset-react is installed but still doesn't parse JSX

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I am writing an express server and all I want is for one of the endpoints to render a React component on the server-side and return the result. At the moment, I'm getting stuck with this error:

```js
    res.send(renderToString(<h1>hello world</h1>))
                            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

I'm trying to run the script with babel-node and based my approach on the strategies outlined in [this thread from a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181682/using-express-and-es6-to-render-react-and-jsx-server-side). I installed `@babel/preset-react` but to no avail.

**.babelrc**

```json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", ["@babel/preset-react", {
     "development": true
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@loadable/babel-plugin"]
}
```

**Start script**

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js"
}
```

**Endpoint**

```js
app.get('/dev/edit', (req, res) => {
  const { dehydrated } = req.body
  console.log('Received edit request.')

  // top of file: import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server.js'
  res.send(renderToString(<h1>hello world</h1>))
})
```

Any help to would be very much appreciated!